How can I get clang-format to keep 3 statements in a switch/case in one line?
This code
case 0xfc: printf("CM     $%02x%02x",code[2],code[1]); opbytes = 3; break;
case 0xfd: printf("CALL   $%02x%02x",code[2],code[1]); opbytes = 3; break;
case 0xfe: printf("CPI    #$%02x",code[1]); opbytes = 2; break;

turns into
case 0xfc:
  printf("CM     $%02x%02x", code[2], code[1]);
  opbytes = 3;
  break;
case 0xfd:
  printf("CALL   $%02x%02x", code[2], code[1]);
  opbytes = 3;
  break;
case 0xfe:
  printf("CPI    #$%02x", code[1]);
  opbytes = 2;
  break;

When I format it, it turns a perfectly readable and compact 3 line of switch cases to 12 line of totally unnecessarily formatted code.
case 0xf1: printf("POP    PSW"); break;

stays as
case 0xf1: printf("POP    PSW"); break;

but when adding one more statement it reformats it:
case 0xf1:
  printf("POP    PSW");
  opbytes = 3;
  break;

What would be the appropiate config to prevent this?
My current .clang-format:
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: "true"
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: "true"
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: WithoutElse
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ColumnLimit: 150

We are not exceeding the 150 character column limit. I am at line 230, column 79. even if something wonky happens, we have 71 character leeway until column limit.
I'm using Apple's CLang (version 17.0.6) which is almost 2 versions behind Linux CLang (version 19).

It's kind of subjective when to use which style. I agree that switch statements with single-line case are more readable but only if the items on each row line up directly underneath each other, so that you can easily spot differences and error. But for non-trivial switch statements, the latter style is better.

AllowShortCaseExpressionOnASingleLine might be the correct setting but it's only available on clang-format 19.
The other (ugly) option is to prevent formatting all together on that piece of code by using // clang-format off and // clang-format on before and after each case:.

... or surrounding the whole switch
